# What chess app displays the name of the opening being used in the game?

Tags: opening, engines

I used to have a chess app that would say the name of the opening being used when you played. Then my tablet broke, and I thought it would be easy to find that chess app, but no luck.

Does anyone know what app I'm talking about, or another app that says the name of the opening being used when you play it?

Comment: Many chess apps could do this, such as chessbase.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't likely to be the app you were using, but the Stockfish iOS app *displays* it:

[image]

(if you play more moves, the ECO code and opening name may change, to e.g. A81 Dutch defense)

I suspect many more (or even most) apps do it, or have at least an option to enable it in the settings. Stockfish does not *say* the name of the opening, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the analysis on *Chess Play & Learn*, it displays the name of the opening.